# HTML Forms within a While loop

Tags: php, html

I have a page that generates invite keys for users who request access to a website.

```
<section id="beta">
    <span class="title">Users Requesting an Invite</span>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>#</li>
            <li>Email</li>
            <li>Invite Code</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        </br>
        <ul>
            <?
                $i = 1;
                while($request = mysql_fetch_array($reqlist)) {
            ?>
            <span>
            <li><?=$i?></li>
            <li><?=$request['email']?></li>
            <?php if(isset($request['invite_code']) && !empty($request['invite_code'])) {?>
                <li><?=$request['invite_code'];?></li>
            <?} elseif(empty($request['invite_code'])) {?>
                <li><?if($onum == $i){echo $invcode;}?></li>
                <li>
                    <form id="<?=$i?>" method="post">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="num" value="<?=$i?>"/>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <?php if($onum == $i && isset($invcode) && !empty($invcode)) {?>
                <li>
                    <form method="post" name="save"> 
                        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="inv" value="<?=$invcode?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="req_id" value="<?=$request['id']?>" />
                    </form>
                </li>
                <? } ?>
            <? } ?> 
        </br>
        </span>
        <?
            $i++;
            //$invcode = '';
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

So as my code states the process is as follows. The table prints out all the users requesting an invite with a generate button at the end. Once generate is clicked I have a function that creates a variable with the key in it. Once the key is generated a new `<li>` with the form save pops up so that it can be saved in the database.

But the problem is that when generate is clicked it only works for the first record. I understand that its due to `$invcode = '';` making it `NULL` but I am not sure how to do it differently so that if any generate button is clicked it will only work for the specific person.

**UPDATE:** Updated with working answer. Also seems like I worded the question wrong. Only the first row would generate a code at a time. The saving for each individual row works completely fine. Its just that every generate button will only work on the first row if $invcode is not set.  But I fixed it by adding the row number to the mix.

Comment: hi just an off topic, if it would help to make your code to be more readable i would like to suggest that you use something like this `http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php`. I had trouble tracing to which context owns the nested `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the criticism, will look into the new way of coding since some items are deprecated. But figured out how to fix it anyway.

I added `<input type="hidden" name="num" value="<?=$i?>"/>` to the generate form and have it check that if the post number equals to the line number if it matches it echos. `if($onum == $i){echo $invcode;}`

Answer (score 0):

try using -

```
<input type="submit" name="save[]" value="Save" />
<input type="hidden" name="inv[]" value="<?=$invcode?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="req_id[]" />
```

You are getting value of first row because of same input type name. you need to use [] after name to get all value within that name

and you may need to change the code where you are submitting the value. On submit page `print_r` variable to see.

Example -

```
print_r($_POST['inv']);
```

It will output an array and i hope rest things you can do alone :)

Comment: Thanks, but that actually was not the area the problem was happening. It was here `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" />`   but I fixed it.